# module in repo not found in local version of python package

Tags: python, pip, sympy

I would like to use the `physics.quantum.TensorProduct' method in`sympy`. Looking at [the repo](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/tree/master/sympy/physics/quantum) this method definitely exists. However when attempting to import into my python session I get the following:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> physics.quantum.TensorProduct(v1,v2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#271>", line 1, in <module>
    physics.quantum.TensorProduct(v1,v2)
AttributeError: module 'sympy.physics' has no attribute 'quantum'
```

I installed sympy seamlessly using `pip` as `pip install sympy`. If I try to upgrade `pip install sympy --upgrade` I get the `Requirement already up-to-date` message.

Why is this that this script is not included? How can I get it so that it is downloaded from the repo and recognized in my python session?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the installed sympy version matches the one in the repository ? Maybe run a `pip freeze` to see what version of the packages you installed.

Comment: `pip freeze` shows that I am using `sympy 1.1.1`. How do I know which version the repository is now at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `physics` package is not imported in `sympy.__init__.__all__` so you cannot access it in your local scope with a simple `from sympy import *`

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> 'physics' in dir()
False
```

Instead you could import the class you want manually. For example :

```
>>> import sympy.physics.quantum.tensorproduct
>>> sympy.physics.quantum.tensorproduct.TensorProduct
<class 'sympy.physics.quantum.tensorproduct.TensorProduct'>
```